# NVME SSD Slow Windows Loading on consecutive boots

Tags: ssd, performance, storage

I have a strange problem with my new [EVO 970 SSD](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evo/). For some reason, when my PC starts to boot into Windows 10 (when the circle starts spinning) it takes around 10-15 seconds, which is a bit too much for an NVMe.

There is a catch though: If the computer had been turned off for a few hours, Windows loads pretty much instantly (just as it should be on an NVMe drive).

Also sometimes re-plugging the SSD into the M2 slot helps, but not every time.

So it means that the first boot of the day is usually very fast and if I were to restart the computer throughout the day, the loading would take significantly longer than normal.

Note: I do not include the POST times in my calculations and I only count the loading times from the moment the windows circle shows up. The POST load time is always the same as opposed to the Windows load time.

Things I tried:
Installing latest BIOS,
Installing Samsung NVME driver,
Enabling/disabling fast boot in both windows and BIOS, disabling CSM, connecting my SSD to Asus Hyper extension card

I am at a loss as to why this happens and why it works properly if the PC had been turned off for a while

My PC:
[ASUS x99 Deluxe II](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99-DELUXE-II/)  [motherboard & BIOS manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/X99-DLX_II/E11357_X99-DELUXE_II_UM_WEB.pdf)
[i7 5820k](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/x-series/i7-5820k.html)
GTX 1080
32 GB RAM

Comment: A) Is there anything in the PCIeX16_3 Slot? That takes half the bandwidth available to the drive according to your motherboard manual, page 3-23. B) In the BIOS/Setup, is U.2_2 Bandwidth set to [Auto]?

Comment: Have you compared times for "_shutdown and then power up again_" with "_restart_"?

Comment: You guys have made some good suggestions. I got nothing else in my PCI-E slots except for my sole GPU. The bandwidth is set to auto.

Comment: As for shutdown and power again, you're absolutely right. Though it still works kinda weirdly and inconsistent. So I've just tried to shut down and power up and it loaded pretty much instantly. I thought I finally figured it out but then I shut down and power up 2 more times. On the 3rd time, the long loading was back again. I did some research and some people claim that x99 bios can be buggy and fastboot may not always work. One guy suggested to test it by hibernating  Win10 and then turning it back on and shutting down completely again. And the fast boot works every time after doing this!

Comment: This leads me to believe that it could indeed be some sort of a bug with BIOS or Windows 10 fast startup. I'd be happy if someone proved me wrong though

Comment: Looks like a thermal issue or bad contact or both (bad contact causes overheating)

Comment: It seems to happen on both the M2 slot and the extension card so I am not so sure about the contacts. CrystalDiskInfo informs me that the temps are around 49 C which isn't so bad, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved. The culprit was my gaming mouse. Upon disconnecting it from my PC, loading times went back to normal. Right now I disabled the USB initialization in BIOS so it works perfectly.

Comment: If it's still working as expected tomorrow, please clean up the Question and Answer, and mark as Answered.  Thanks for trying out the USB settings.   I suggest trying the original USB initialization settings, starting with nothing plugged into USB, rebooting repeatedly until you experience the problem.  You may find that one of the USB devices is the culprit, and just unplug it when you shut down.

Comment: Honestly I am a bit afraid of messing with it now, as it works properly now. What I do know is that it's either the keyboard or the mouse because Partial initalization (kb+mouse only) has got the same problem

Comment: Looks like I figured it out finally... What a pain that was. I will mark it as solved tomorrow because I can't do it right now for some reason